# Unable to dynamically run SQL query

Tags: java, groovy

In Groovy, I want to be able to execute a truncate query dynamically. However, I know the following won't work as `${s}.${x}` needs to be interpolated before being sent to `sql.execute`. But what is the best and safest method to be able to run the below?

```
for (String s : schema) {
  for (String x : table) {
    try {
      sql.execute "TRUNCATE ${s}.${x}" ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      println e
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think ${s}.${x} is not interpolated before being sent to sql.execute()? What happens when you run that code?

Answer (score 0):

```
sql.execute( "TRUNCATE ${s}.${x}".toString())
```